# How to disconnect derivative objects in getter from Vuex store state?

Tags: vuex

I have a Vuex getter like this:

```
    sectionsAndSubSectionsJoined(state) {
        var sections = state.aBMudbone.sections;
        var subsections = state.aBMudbone.subSections;

        var combinedSections = [];

        _.forEach(sections, function (section) {
            var subSectionsFiltered = _.filter(subsections, ['sectionId', section.sectionId]);
            var sectionAndSubSections = section;
            sectionAndSubSections.children = subSectionsFiltered;
            combinedSections.push(sectionAndSubSections);
        });

       return combinedSections
    }
```

In the console I get the following error:

```
[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

The line it shows this error for is :

```
sectionAndSubSections.children = subSectionsFiltered;
```

As I understand it, even though `sections`, `subSections` and `sectionAndSubSections` are new objects, because they are created from the store state they are subject to some binding hence the warning when I try to add to this state.

***How can I disconnect this new state from the store state so I don't get this warning?***